# Umbrella Base Rusting Concrete

Tags: metal, rust

I have a cantilever umbrella which has a metal base (an x). To hold the umbrella and the x metal base we’ve used the plastic umbrella base, which comes with 4 blocks that are filled with water.

But the metal x causes rust on the stamped concrete. I will clean the rust but what’s the best way to prevent the rust on the concrete in the future? Should I place a thin mat under or can the metal be sprayed with something?

Answer (score 2):

Paint the metal base. Remove all of the rust that you can and remove any loose paint. Then you want to prime it with a zinc rich primer. A big hardware store should have "cold galvanizing" paint/spray/etc. in a spray can. That's the stuff that you want to use to prepare the surface before applying a top coat. Applying a few coats will give better protection than a single coat, so go nuts. Finally apply your top coat.

If the metal base drags across abrasive surfaces, then get it up on some sort of pads like you would for a piece of furniture scratching hardwood floors.